# How to refer robot framework user defined keyword in another user defined keyword

Tags: robotframework

I am very new to `robot framework`, barely days old...
I am looking to automate one of our web app using `Robot Framework` and I am using Page Object Model setup where

1. I have keywords defined in a file `(Resources/fileKeywords.robot)`
2. I also have a `location.py` file in a separate folder `(PageObjects/locators.py)` which contains web elements.
3. Test cases are defined in a separate folder called `"TestCases"`

Now I have a situation like this in my app.
I must choose a `CSV` file to upload within the app.
For that, there is a browse button which I must click which will open windows file open dialog and from there it will select a `CSV` file from a specific folder and click "Open" in file dialog to complete file selection.
After the file is selected there is a button to `"Import"` the selected file.
After that, the file gets displayed in a table and I must click on the appropriate uploaded file to proceed further.

For this I've defined few keywords like this
*** Keywords ***

```
File name for Upload
   ${CSVfileName}=  read_csv_file   ${CsvFileFolder} #read_csv_file is a python class which returns csv 
     file. Let's say acb.csv

Click uploaded file
   click element ${CSVfileName}
```

In `Click uploaded file`, I am trying to refer the `${CSVfileName}` scalar variable inside the `html` element to perform click action on the uploaded file
`(like xpath://span[contains(text(),'abc.csv')`]
but i am getting error. It says "Variable definition not found"

I can keep both under the same keyword and call that keyword from my Testcase. But I want to separate out for more clarity.

All I want to know is:
How to I refer a user defined variable(in my case `${CSVfileName}`) from a keyword (in my case 'File name for Upload') in another keyword section (in my case 'Click uploaded file')

Sorry if I am bit confusing or if it doesn't belong to the correct forum.
Appreciate all your assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing to find what you mean. But I'll try and if it's not correct because I didn't understand something, say so in the comments.

I think you have these two keywords:

```
*** Keywords ***
File name for Upload
    ...
    ${CSVfileName}= ...
    ...

Click uploaded file
    ...
```

Now, if I understand it, you create the variable `${CSVfileName}` in `File name for Upload` and you want to use the variable in `Click uploaded file`.

In that case, you have roughly 2 options:

1/ You define the variable in `File name for Upload` as global variable with keyword `Set Global Variable`

```
*** Keywords ***
File name for Upload
    ...
    Set Global Variable    ${CSVfileName}    ...
    ...


Click uploaded file
    ...
    ${CSVfileName}= ...
    ...
```

The disadvantage is that you need to make sure that `File name for Upload` will be always called before every other usage of the variable. The variable declaration and assignment is also hidden in the keyword, which makes it a bit less clear in my opinion.

2/ You return from `File name for Upload` and parametrize `Click uploaded file`:

```
*** Keywords ***
File name for Upload
    ...
    ${CSVfileName}    ...
    [Return]    ${CSVfileName}
    ...

Click uploaded file
    [Arguments]    ${CSVfileName}
    ...
```

And you'd most likely use it in a test like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Upload File Test
    ...
    ${CSVfileName}=    File name for Upload
    Click uploaded file    ${CSVfileName}
    ...
```

This other solution makes it more flexible, and also clear. You see immediately you need to provide some parameters before you actually call a keyword. The keywords could be called in any order, which makes them more independent.